# Modify image obtained from loopback-component-storage

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using `loopback` for storing Image to the `server`.

I want to **modify** the **file name** of the file before getting saved to the server.

Also I want to convert it to another thumbnail form before getting saved.

Here is how I am doing.

> At client side

```
Upload.upload(
{
    url: '/api/containers/container_name/upload',
    file: file,
    fileName: "demoImage.jpg",
    //Additional data with file
    params:{
     orderId: 1, 
     customerId: 1
    }
});
```

> At Server Side I am receiving the query "params" but not getting the "File Name"

My Storage model name is `container`

```
Container.beforeRemote('upload', function(ctx,  modelInstance, next) {

    //OUPTUTS: {orderId:1, customerId:1]}
    console.log(ctx.req.query);

    //Now I want to change the File Name of the file.
    //But not getting how to do that

    next();
})
```

**How to change the File name of the File getting saved at the server?**

Comment: Did you find solution to do this from beforeRemote?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I figured it out.

We have to define a custom function **getFileName** in `boot/configure-storage.js`.

Suppose my **datasource** for `loopback-component-storage` is **presImage**.

> server/boot/configure-storage.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    //Function for checking the file type..
    app.dataSources.presImage.connector.getFilename = function(file, req, res) {

        //First checking the file type..
        var pattern = /^image\/.+$/;
        var value = pattern.test(file.type);
        if(value ){
            var fileExtension = file.name.split('.').pop();
            var container = file.container;
            var time = new Date().getTime();
            var query = req.query;
            var customerId = query.customerId;
            var orderId    = query.orderId;

            //Now preparing the file name..
            //customerId_time_orderId.extension
            var NewFileName = '' + customerId + '_' + time + '_' + orderId + '.' + fileExtension; 

            //And the file name will be saved as defined..
            return NewFileName;
        }
        else{
            throw "FileTypeError: Only File of Image type is accepted.";
        }
    };
}
```

> common/models/container.js

Now suppose my container model is `container`.

```
module.exports = function(Container) {
    Container.afterRemote('upload', function(ctx,  modelInstance, next) {
      var files = ctx.result.result.files.file;

      for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        var ModifiedfileName = files[i].name;
        console.log(ModifiedfileName) //outputs the modified file name.
      } //for loop
      next();
    }); //afterRemote..
};
```

Now for converting it images to **Thumbnail size**

Download the [quickthumb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quickthumb)

Here is how to use it with loopback.

This code is copied directly from [Loopback thumbnail view](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/uYyN8ttj9iY)

> common/models/container.js

```
module.exports = function(Container) {

    var qt = require('quickthumb');

    Container.afterRemote('upload', function(ctx, res, next) {

        var file = res.result.files.file[0];
        var file_path = "./server/storage/" + file.container + "/" + file.name;
        var file_thumb_path = "./server/storage/" + file.container + "/thumb/" + file.name;

        qt.convert({
            src: file_path,
            dst: file_thumb_path,
            width: 100
        }, function (err, path) {

        });

        next();
    });

};
```

Comment: Nice response, but i think that the orderId, customerId should be set in server side and not set in the form so it can not be changed by the final user.

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on the answer above, this configure-storage enables the file name to be set explicitly via `req.params.filename` and to default to the existing name if none is provided.

> configure-storage.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {

//Function for checking the file type..
    app.dataSources.storage.connector.getFilename = function(file, req, ignoreRes) {

        if (!req.params.filename) {
            return file.name
        }

        var fileExtension = file.name.split('.').pop()
        return req.params.filename + '.' + fileExtension

    };
}
```