# Validate and Rename Image file from loopback-component-storage

Tags: upload, storage, loopbackjs, file-type

I got the similar question as [Modify image obtained from loopback-component-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048618/modify-image-obtained-from-loopback-component-storage) but the answer is not satisfactory to me.

Use the same example :

> At client side

```js
Upload.upload(
{
    url: '/api/containers/container_name/upload',
    file: file,
    fileName: "demoImage.jpg",
    //Additional data with file
    params:{
     username : username
    }
});
```

Here is the requirement:

1. Validate the file type of the file
2. Modify the name saved in server
3. Reject if invalid file or username

Here is some reference that I used and encountered :

- The username is required, so it should be a user's method. I added a remote method like it is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31118294/5241407 and changed the api into /api/usermodel/:id/upload. Some codes were add in remoteMethod to send username to `container.upload` function. Is it possible that we valid the file type and change the file name in this phase so that I can return error if the it is invalid ?
- I used configure-storage.js in boot file as it is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31059880/5241407 But this solution is inadequate. If the client send invalid filetype the server will throw error, which is not expected. It is better to reject the query with a error response instead of throw a system error. So how to return error without throw a error in system level?
- Once I upload a png file and checked the file.type in configure-storage.js, only to find that the file type is application/octet-stream instead of image/png. This is the code I used to probe: `curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --header "Accept: application/json" "HOST/api/usermodel/userId/upload" -F "filename=@a.png"` This unexpected result may hinder the judgement of file type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I had done to validate the file type and modifying the file name,

in `datasources.local.js` [container name is `container`]

```
module.exports = {
  container: {
    root: './upload',
    acl: 'public-read',
    allowedContentTypes: ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/tiff'],
    maxFileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
    getFilename: function(fileInfo) {
      var fileName = fileInfo.name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
      return 'image-' + new Date().getTime() + '-' + fileName;
    }
  }
};
```

Rejection of request should be handled via ACLs for authentication and authorization check. Reject based on file names can be done by a remote hook.

Below is a sample (I didn't test this)

```
Container.beforeRemote('create', function(context, comment, next) {
  if (context.req.body.fileName.length < 7) {
    context.res.statusCode = 401;
    next(new Error('Filename is too short!'));
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

I hope this can help you to figure out to the way you want.

Comment: Yeah, remote method you can customize. Content types should be fine i believe.

Comment: Thanks. But allowedContentTypes still cannot solve the `application/octet-stream` problem. I find the reason that MINI type should be defined when sending file. BTW the method of beforeRemote should be upload instead of create.