# how to access request body/parameters in loopback beforeRemote/afterRemote method?

Tags: node.js, express, model, loopbackjs, strongloop

i am using loop back storage component for file upload. request contains both file and user data. After file upload, i need user data to save file info. I am trying to access user data using beforeRemote method and afterRemote method as below:

```
Storages.beforeRemote('upload', function (context, unused, next) {
     console.log(context.req.body)

    next();
});

Storages.afterRemote('upload', function (context, unused, next) {
     console.log(context.req.body)
    next();
});
```

but it did not work. is there any way to access request params in remote methods?

Comment: For more info on accessing and modifying request param for file upload check it out:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048618/modify-image-obtained-from-loopback-component-storage/31059880#31059880

Answer (score 0):

I can access the request data in context.a result which looks like

```
{
    result: {
        files: {
            file: [object]
        },
        {
            fields: {
                name: [object]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

files are your uploaded file and fields is your form fields.

Answer (score -1):

You can get body data inside `context.args.data`

Try:

```
Storages.beforeRemote('upload', function (context, unused, next) {
    console.log(context.args.data)
    next();
});
```